# with server side meteor, why is "module" not defined?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm using some node code that has

```
module.exports  = a;
```

which gives:

```
ReferenceError: module is not defined
```

then separately what are the recommended workarounds? I'd prefer to have some simple known code than install a package that "magically" makes this work.

how is this the case? does meteor server code somehow run in something is not node? I understand we have fibers wrapping but i didn't think you could "undefine" something that is fundamental to the node environment?

`W20150202-16:07:12.555(-8)? (STDERR) /Users/dc/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.40.prjwsp++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150202-16:07:12.555(-8)? (STDERR)                            throw(ex);
W20150202-16:07:12.555(-8)? (STDERR)                                  ^
W20150202-16:07:12.596(-8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: module is not defined
W20150202-16:07:12.596(-8)? (STDERR)     at __coffeescriptShare (packages/dcsan:ribot/vendor/rivescript-js/lib/rivescript.js:2913:1)
W20150202-16:07:12.596(-8)? (STDERR)     at RiveScript (packages/dcsan:ribot/vendor/rivescript-js/lib/rivescript.js:2910:1)
W20150202-16:07:12.596(-8)? (STDERR)     at __coffeescriptShare (packages/dcsan:ribot/vendor/rivescript-js/lib/rivescript.js:2911:1)
W20150202-16:07:12.597(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/dc/dev/shumi/chatU/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/dcsan_ribot.js:2937:4
W20150202-16:07:12.597(-8)? (STDERR)     at packages/dcsan:ribot/both/startup.coffee:13:23
W20150202-16:07:12.597(-8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/dc/dev/shumi/chatU/app/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:205:10`

Answer (score 1):

Meteor uses the `vm` module to create new contexts. I suspect so does plain node.js too, there is nothing "fundamental" about the keyword `module`. Under the hood node.js loader wraps all files into closures and passes special variables such as `__dirname` into them.

http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing the same error, and deleting the node_modules directory from my meteor project did the trick.

What has not been made clear in any of the articles or README file is that **all** you need is the `packages.json` file.  I thought I needed to install the npm's myself, but that is wrong, and those installed npm's conflict with the ones that meteorhacks:npm installs, based on `packages.json`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when trying to define Cucumber steps for Chimp. I managed to resolve it by wrapping the `module.exports` like this:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  module.exports = function() {
    ...
  };
})();
```

Did that work for you?